# PHP/JS: cannot get

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

All I want to do is print 'win!' if they log in with their details in the Database (working correctly) and 'loss' if for some reason their info was not found in the DB.

So my issue is that for some reason my line of code 'echo $email;' doesn't work. It seems be set to NULL.

At the moment it only ever prints 'loss' regardless what i enter, but, if I add a row in the database that has a blank email and password (email = "", password="") then the php script returns 'win!'.

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
// echo "php test";
//server info
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$dbpassword = "root";
$dbname = "personal_data";


//Establish server connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $dbpassword, $dbname);


//Check connection for failure 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//Read in email & password
echo "reading in email & password...";
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email1']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password1']); 
echo $email; //this prints blank
echo $password; //this also prints blank

$sql = "SELECT Name FROM personal_data WHERE Email='$email' AND Password='$password' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "win!!";
    } else {
        echo "loss";
    }

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// alert("js working");

$('#login_button').click(function(){
    var email = $('#email').val(); //prints the correct value
    var password = $('#password').val(); //prints the correct value

var dataString = 'email1=' + email 
               + '&password1=' + password;

$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8888/php/login.php",
                data: dataString,   //posts to PHP script
                success: success()
            });

});//eo login_button

function success(){
alert("success");
}

});//eof
```

Comment: Try `var dataString = {email1 : email, password1 : password};` and pass that directly to the `data` option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the fact that that is completely, insanely useless and with no security whatsoever, you can just exchange `$.ajax()` for `$.post()` and do like this:

```
var loginEmail = $('#email').val();
var loginPassword = $('#password').val();

$.post('login.php',{email:loginEmail,password1:loginPassword},function(data) {
console.log(data);
})
```